# unable to insert data in SQLite database using floating button AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am new to android programming, i am planning to build Todo app 
i have made DatabaseHelper.java file and everything is currect (i have used it ealier)

problem- on cliking floatingbutton AlertDialog box opens and some problem occur while inserting data myDB.addData(task) unable to find error help me out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("New Task")
                    .setMessage("Add a new Task")
                    .setView(editText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = editText.getText().toString();
                            boolean isInserted = myDB.addData(task);
                            if(isInserted == true){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"inseretd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

helper file- DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MyTodo.db";
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "MyTodo_Table";
    public final static String COL_1 ="ID";
    public final static String COL_2 ="Data";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATA TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean addData(String data){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,data);

    long result =db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

app get crached with  -

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.todo, PID: 3629
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.todo.DatabaseHelper.addData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.todo.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3629 SIG: 9

Comment: All you need is in your stacktrace. It's useful experience to analyse it even if you are new to Android programming. It will give you more than ready answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing:

```
db.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Is using this.getReadableDatabase(); both read and write can be performed... No effect app still crashes 

Comment: You're right, I checked the documentation now. In that case, it could be that you're missing db.beginTransaction() before you do the insert. Let me know if that's the case and I will update the answer.